# Derivation of a second order PDE

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

currently I notice a secord order PDE named [transport-of-intensity equation](https://inis.iaea.org/search/search.aspx?orig_q=RN:27020490) (see page 6 of this paper).

The equation if as follow:
\begin{equation}
    \left(\nabla_{\perp}^{2}+2 i k \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) U_{A}(\mathbf{x}, z)=0,
\end{equation}
where $\nabla_{\perp}^{2}$ is the transverse Laplacian operator deﬁned by $\nabla_{\perp}^{2}=\left(\partial^{2} / \partial x_{1}^{2}+\partial^{2} / \partial x_{2}^{2}\right)$ and $z$ denotes the propagation direction. The varying component $U_{A}(\mathbf{x}, z)= \sqrt{I(\mathbf{x}, z)}\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z)).$

My question is about secord order Laplacian and my solution of that part is is:
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
    \nabla_{\perp}^{2} I(\mathbf{x}, z)^{\frac{1}{2}}\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z))  = & \nabla_{\perp} \cdot \left[  \nabla_{\perp}( \ I(\mathbf{x}, z)^{\frac{1}{2}}\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z)) \ ) \right] \\ =& \nabla_{\perp} \cdot \left[ \frac{1}{2}I(\mathbf{x}, z)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z)) \nabla I(\mathbf{x}, z) +\\ i\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z))I(\mathbf{x}, z)^{\frac{1}{2}} \nabla \phi((\mathbf{x}, z)) \right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I dont know whether my partial dervation is right. Could anyone tell me?

Besides, could I eliminate the $\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z))$ before excuting the second order derivative (the result from $2 i k \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \sqrt{I(\mathbf{x}, z)}\exp(i\phi(\mathbf{x}, z))$ has the same term) ?

Could anyone show the hints for the following calculation? Thanks!

Comment: In your second line, you are trying to take the dot product of a vector and a scalar which doesn't make sense. Note that $\nabla_{\perp} (I^{1/2} \exp(\cdot))$ should return a vector.

Comment: @Mattos Oh, yes, you are right! That means the derivation of first order derivative is wrong... Could you give some hints about true derivation? Thanks

Comment: It's essentially just an application of the product rule. I'll compute $\partial_{x_{1}}$. You can do $\partial_{x_{2}}, \partial_{z}$. Then put each in a vector i.e $\nabla_{\perp}I \exp(\cdot) = [\partial_{x_{1}} (I \exp(\cdot)), \partial_{x_{2}} (I \exp(\cdot)), \partial_{z} (I \exp(\cdot))]$. We have \begin{align} \partial_{x_{1}} [I^{1/2}(x_{1},x_{2},z) \exp(i \phi(x_{1},x_{2},z))] &= \partial_{x_{1}}[I^{1/2}] \exp(i \phi) + I^{1/2} \partial_{x_{1}} [\exp(i \phi)] \\
&= \frac{1}{2} I^{-1/2} \partial_{x_{1}}I \exp(i \phi) + I^{1/2} \cdot i \partial_{x_{1}} \phi \exp(i \phi) \end{align}

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for your help! Finally I finish the correct derivation. But I want to know whether I could calculate the derivative of $(x_1,x_2)$ in total instead of splitting for one by one calculation?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'calculate the derivative of $(x_{1},x_{2})$ in total'. For a general function, you don't know the dependence of either $I$ or $\phi$ on any of the variables a priori, hence you just need to compute the derivatives. In this case, you literally just had to change $\partial_{x_{1}}$ from my example to $\partial_{x_{2}}$ and $\partial_{z}$.

Comment: @Mattos Your suggestion for the derivative is to compute $\partial_{x1}$, $\partial_{x2}$ and $\partial_{z}$ respectively and combine all the terms. What I mean is could I calculate $\nabla$ directly instead of calculating respectively?